# How to make formatoptions+=a useful?

Tags: formatting

I was interested in the `set formatoptions+=a` option, but even if the idea of reformatting comment in my code or even markdown text is seducing, I cannot really use the feature because I cannot write something like:

```
Heading
=======
Some Text
```

Immediately, Vim will reformat this as follow:

```
Heading ======= Some Text
```

What I need to do is insert a blank line between each entry:

```
Heading

=======

Some Text
```

Which is not very convenient.

Is there another option that makes this `a` option a bit smarter?

**EDIT**

Another example:

```
/**
 * Heading.
 * A function that does something
 * @param foo Foo
 */
```

Will be automatically reformatted:

```
/** Heading. A function that does something @param foo Foo
 */
```

Comment: `:set fo+=ac` works mostly as advertised, just not for Markdown.

Comment: Well, it does not work with my example (see my edit) :(

Comment: It works _as advertised_.  That is, it autoformats comments, not the code. :)

Comment: Try `:set fo+=w` if you don't mind a trailing space to indicate that a paragraph continues.

Comment: @Antony Yep this is pretty much what I was looking for

Comment: Cool. Answer added for the archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `a` in `'formatoptions'`,

```
:set formatoptions+=w
```

can help with the automatic formatting.
It means that lines ending with trailing space indicate that
the paragraph continues on the next line. The
trailing space is automatically added when the
line is broken while typing, editing, or when formatting with `gq`.

A line without trailing space indicates that a
paragraph ends at that line, so hitting `<Enter>`
will end a paragraph.

Note that this doesn't affect the operation of text objects.
Commands such as `gqap` will format a regular paragraph, but
the formatting will respect the paragraph boundaries
determined by the rules for `w`.